# Why does the container height change when scrolling just past the typed.js span?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typed.js

I've working at this issue for ages and it still seems a mystery. When I scroll just past the typed.js span, the container seems to expand downwards - something that it doesn't do when at the top of the page. Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/apwnv91q/5/) of a bare-bones example.

I've got a [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCTz6.jpg) of the problem happening on the other site.

Apparently I have to provide code with a jsfiddle, so here's the basic structure of the example:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1><span class="typed-text"></span></h1>
  <h2>Subtitle, this doesn't change automatically</h2>
</div>
<div style="height:600px"></div>
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/apwnv91q/21/

Comment: @RKailashShankar If I add a margin to the bottom so that I can scroll down [link](https://jsfiddle.net/apwnv91q/23/), and then scroll so that the text is just out of view, it still jumps around.

Comment: Your js fiddle works how you want it to, unlike the gif you've shown here. Would be better if you show the real code.

Comment: I still get the issue with the jsfiddle, I'm using chrome version 64.0.3282.186 mac, at 1280 x 800. Could it be a browser dependent bug?

Comment: Here's a gif demonstrating the bug in jsfiddle - http://recordit.co/qXIvB5AORU

Comment: This is my advice: since the height of the container is varying due to the varying lengths of characters in the `<h1>`, make the height of `<h1>` in the container a fixed number(so that it would fit the largest string). Now that you have a container of a fixed and stable height, try increasing the blank division's height so that the container can be fully overridden by the blank division while scrolling.